# Не работает форма поиска, как найти причину?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css3, html5

Не работает форма поиска, как найти причину? На нажатие мыши форма не реагирует, только при нажатии tab! Как исправить данный баг?

[Ссылка на сайт](http://35.170.225.58/)

Comment: хоть бы "заглушки" поставил вместо неприемлемых картинок=)))

Comment: а может кому-то это приемлимые картинки?)

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев, не могу спорить, так как большая часть аудитории - мужчины(очевидно), но политика данного ресурса такое не одобряет, насколько я знаю

Comment: @Arthur вопрос по верстке, при чем тут картинки?

Comment: @eprivalov1, своё мнение я выразил, но это не значит, что я против этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте контейнеру с формой(`#av_section_1 > .av-section-color-overlay-wrap .container`) `position: relative;` `z-index: 2;`, так как у вас диагональный блок(его родитель) перекрывает форму, поэтому и не срабатывает клик.